# Error freeing C** pointer malloced in function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

The program runs fine except for the last free, which results in the program freezing.
When I comment out the last 'free' it runs fine.

The program gets all substrings from a string and returns it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** getPrefixes(char* invoer);

int main()
{
    char buffer[100];
    char *input;
    char **prefixes;
    int counter = 0;

    puts("Give string.");
    fgets(buffer, 99, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    if (buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] == '\n')
        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';

    input= (char*)malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);

    if (input == NULL)
    {
        puts("Error allocating memory.");
        return;
    }

    strcpy(input, buffer);

    prefixes = (char**) getPrefixes(input);

    for (counter = strlen(input); counter > 0;  counter--)
    {
        puts(prefixes[counter]);
        free(prefixes[counter]);
    }

    free(input);

    free(prefixes);
}

char** getPrefixes(char* input)
{
    char** prefixes;
    int counter;

    prefixes = malloc(strlen(input) * sizeof(char*));

    if (prefixes == NULL)
    {
        puts("ELM.");
        return NULL;
    }


    for (counter= strlen(input); counter> 0; counter--)
    {
        prefixes[counter] = (char*)malloc(counter + 1);
        strcpy(prefixes[counter], input);
        input++;
    }

    return prefixes;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is **teller** ? It is neither defined nor initialized.

Comment: Just `free`ing `prefixes` is not enough, you need to `free` individual `prefixes[i]` as well.

Comment: `@MichaelWalz: `teller` is dutch for `counter`, I take it the OP translated part of the code prior to pasting it, but not all of it, just like `getPrefixes(char* input)` is `getPrefixes(char* invoer)` higher up

Comment: To the OP: In C, you _do not cast the return value of `malloc` calls_. When it comes to allocating memory, a `void` pointer is what you need. And don't forget: ***arrays are zero-indexed***, check your loops. and realize that `char[] "foo"` is strlen 3, but the last o is found @ index (offset) 2!!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `prefixes[teller] = (char*)malloc(counter + 1);` is not what you really want.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any reason why you need to do all this copying around? Why not just call puts with different pointers into buffer?

Comment: Teller was indeed meant to be counter, forgot to translate every variable, my bad.
@thisisdog, part of the exercise.

Comment: @DriesWielockx: cf my answer, I've set up a complete -and working- codepad, and explain why your program hangs, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your program freezing is simple: undefined behaviour + invalid return values: _Your main function returns `void`, not an `int`: add `return 0` ASAP! If you type in `echo $?` in your console after executing your compiled binary, you should see a number other than `0`. This is the program's exit code. anything other than 0 means trouble. if the `main` did not return an int, it's bad news.

Next:
The undefined behaviour occurs in a couple of places, for example right here:

```
prefixes = malloc(strlen(input) * sizeof(char*));
//allocate strlen(input) pointers, if input is 10 long => valid indexes == 0-9
for (counter= strlen(input); counter> 0; teller--)
{//teller doesn't exist, so I assume you meant "counter--"
    prefixes[teller] = (char*)malloc(counter + 1);//first call prefixes[10] ==> out of bounds
    strcpy(prefixes[counter], input);//risky, no zero-termination... use calloc + strncpy
    input++;
}
```

Then, when free-ing the memory, you're not freeing the pointer @ offset 0, so the `free(prefixes)` call is invalid:

```
for (counter = strlen(input); counter > 0;  counter--)
{//again 10 --> valid offsets are 9 -> 0
    puts(prefixes[counter]);
    free(prefixes[counter]);
}
free(prefixes);//wrong
```

Again, valid indexes are 0 and up, your condition in the loop (`counter > 0`) means that the loop breaks whenever `counter` is 0. You, at no point, are freeing the first pointer in the array, the one at index/offstet 0.

Write your loops like everyone would:

```
for (int i=0, size_t len = strlen(input); i<len; ++i)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);//prints 0-9... 10 lines, all valid indexes
}
```

Change your loops, and make sure you're only using the valid offsets and you _should be good to go. using `strncpy`, you can still get the same result as before:

```
for (int i=0;i<len;++i)
{
    //or malloc(i+2), char is guaranteed to be 1
    //I tend to use `calloc` to set all chars to 0 already, and ensure zero-termination
    prefixes[i] = malloc((i+2)*sizeof(*prefixes[i]));
    strncpy(prefixes[i], input, i+1);//max 1 - 10 chars are copied
}
```

If we apply this to your code, and re-write it like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** getPrefixes(char* input);

int main( void )
{
    char *input;
    char **prefixes;
    int counter, i;

    input= calloc(50,1);
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        puts("Error allocating memory.");
        return;
    }
    strcpy(input, "teststring");

    prefixes = getPrefixes(input);
    counter = strlen(input);
    for (i=0; i<counter;++i)
    {
        puts(prefixes[i]);
        free(prefixes[i]);
    }

    free(input);
    free(prefixes);
    return 0;
}

char** getPrefixes(char* input)
{
    int i, counter = strlen(input);
    char** prefixes = malloc(counter * sizeof *prefixes);

    if (prefixes == NULL)
    {
        puts("ELM.");
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i=0; i<counter; ++i)
    {
        prefixes[i] = calloc(i + 2,sizeof *prefixes[i]);
        strncpy(prefixes[i], input, i+1);
    }
    return prefixes;
}
```

The output we get is:

```
t
te
tes
test
tests
testst
teststr
teststri
teststrin
teststring
```

As you can see for yourself

## [on this codepad](http://codepad.org/er0dOgc7)

Answer (score 1):

allocating memory for pointer to pointer:

```
char** cArray = (char**)malloc(N*sizeof(char*));

for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    cArray[i] = (char*)malloc(M*sizeof(char));
```

De-allocating memory - in reverse order:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    free(cArray[i]);
free(cArray)
```

I hope this gives you a little insight on what's wrong.

Comment: You have a point but this doesn't seem to be an answer to `program freezing`

Comment: you have some memory leaks in there when you run your program; this might cause your environment to freeze. I have seen something similar in VS but not freezing, rather taking a long time to finish (tens of seconds) - in what environment are you running this?

Comment: @Pandrei: memory leaks don't usually freeze.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I agree with that statement; I'm just saying what I've noticed - probably something else happening in the background which is linked to memory leaks that causes the behavior...

Comment: @Pandrei: Just be clear with the OP: he's not freeing the pointer @ index/offset 0. Nor is he using it, he's also invoking undefined behaviour by going out of bounds on the `prefixes` array

Answer (score 1):

you are calling strcpy with prefixes[counter] as destination. However, you've only allocated 4/8 bytes per prefixes[counter] depending on the size of (char*)

When you call strcpy you're copying all of input all the way to the end requiring strlen(input)! space

Doing this will corrupt the heap which might explain why the program is freezing.

Comment: `(char*)malloc(counter + 1);` will, worst-case scenario allocate enough memory for 2 chars. The size of `char *` doesn't enter into this. The real issues are: OP seems unaware of zero-indexed arrays and `strcpy` should've been `strncpy`, of course

Comment: NP, because `input++` should avoid overflow, only the zero-termination is an issue